# Tablet version is being viewed on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design, mobile-safari, media-queries, mobile-chrome

I've been making a webpage using Foundation 4 so it is very responsive across all devices.

However, for some odd reason in both Chrome and Safari on iPhone's and mobile in portrait mode (aka should be using the mobile site which is less than 568px wide) it is using the tablet version.

When using your browser and rescaling it to the various sizes, it works absolutely fine, it loads desktop, tablet and mobile.

Why is the mobile site not being used on mobile devices? I'm using all of the foundation media queries so I'm not sure why it isn't working. (I KNOW the mobile site works just fine)

The foundation media queries for mobile is this:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 40em){}
```

Tablet is :

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) and (max-width: 64em) {
```

Comment: you're going to need to add some code

Comment: Why are you using relative `em`s for your breakpoints? Why not use pixel?

Comment: @ChrisHardie it is how foundation is built. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html

Comment: Interesting, I wonder what the value is there given we measure devices in pixels. Ok, are you doing anything that would affect the value of `em`?

Comment: I don't beleive so, I have kept all the foundation defaults relating to media queries